# Modify Makefile to get a simple form for 2 executables

Tags: makefile

Up to now, I used the following `Makefile` to get 2 executables with all sources in the same directory :

```
GFORTRAN    = gfortran -Wall
CC          = gcc -Wall
MPI_FORTRAN = mpif90 -Wall
MPI_CC      = mpicc -Wall
LD = -lm

.SUFFIXES : .o .f90

all: explicitSeq explicitPar

explicitSeq : explicitSeq.o explUtilSeq.o
        $(GFORTRAN) -o $@ explicitSeq.o explUtilSeq.o

explicitSeq.o : explicitSeq.f90
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $(*F).f90

explUtilSeq.o : explUtilSeq.f90
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $(*F).f90

explicitPar : explicitPar.o explUtilPar.o updateBound.o readParam.o
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -o $@ explicitPar.o explUtilPar.o updateBound.o readParam.o

.f90.o:
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -c $(*F).f90

clean :
        /bin/rm -f *.o explicitSeq explicitPar
```

Everything is working fine. Now, I would like to use a basic form using `%.o` and `%.f90` variables combined with "`$<`" variable.

I tried to make the equivalent `Makefile` of above like this :

```
GFORTRAN    = gfortran -Wall
CC          = gcc -Wall
MPI_FORTRAN = mpif90 -Wall
MPI_CC      = mpicc -Wall
LD = -lm

SRC_SEQ = explicitSeq.f90 explUtilSeq.f90
OBJ_SEQ = explicitSeq.o explUtilSeq.o
SRC_PAR = explicitPar.f90 explUtilPar.f90 updateBound.f90 readParam.f90
OBJ_PAR = explicitPar.o explUtilPar.o updateBound.o readParam.o

all: explicitSeq explicitPar

explicitSeq : OBJ_SEQ
        $(GFORTRAN) -o $@ $<

OBJ_SEQ: SRC_SEQ
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $<

explicitPar : OBJ_PAR
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -o $@ $<

OBJ_PAR: SRC_PAR
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -c $<

clean :
        /bin/rm -f *.o explicitSeq explicitPar
```

But unfortunately, typing "make" produces :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `SRC_SEQ', needed by `OBJ_SEQ'.  Stop.
```

I don't know how to circumvent this error. Maybe I should use the dependence `.f90.o:` but I don't know clearly where to put it.

### Update 1

From  Vroomfondel's advice, I did the following modifications :

```
GFORTRAN    = gfortran-mp-4.9 -Wall
CC          = gcc -Wall
MPI_FORTRAN = mpif90 -Wall
MPI_CC      = mpicc -Wall
LD = -lm

SRC_SEQ = explicitSeq.f90 explUtilSeq.f90
OBJ_SEQ = explicitSeq.o explUtilSeq.o
SRC_PAR = explicitPar.f90 explUtilPar.f90 updateBound.f90 readParam.f90
OBJ_PAR = explicitPar.o explUtilPar.o updateBound.o readParam.o

all: explicitSeq explicitPar

explicitSeq : $(OBJ_SEQ)
        $(GFORTRAN) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_SEQ): $(SRC_SEQ)
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $<

explicitPar : $(OBJ_PAR)
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_PAR): $(SRC_PAR)
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -c $<

clean :
        /bin/rm -f *.o explicitSeq explicitPar
```

and I get the errors :

```
gfortran-mp-4.9 -Wall -c explicitSeq.f90
gfortran-mp-4.9 -Wall -c explicitSeq.f90
gfortran-mp-4.9 -Wall -o explicitSeq explicitSeq.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_computenext_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in explicitSeq.o
  "_initvalues_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in explicitSeq.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [explicitSeq] Error 1
```

As you can see, the file `explicitSeq.f90` is compiled 2 times: is it the expected behavior from the modified Makefile?

### Update 2

I think I could use the following rule :

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(GFORTRAN) -o $@ -c $<
```

but the problem is that I have to compile also some `*.f90` files with `$(MPI_FORTRAN)`. I don't know how to differentiate the 2 cases of obj files (*.o) (with gfortan compiler and mpif90 compiler)

### Update 3

I have got almost the solution. I did :

```
GFORTRAN    = gfortran -Wall
CC          = gcc -Wall
MPI_FORTRAN = mpif90 -Wall
MPI_CC      = mpicc -Wall
LD = -lm

DIR_SEQ = tmpSeqDir
DIR_PAR = tmpParDir
SRC_SEQ = explicitSeq.f90 explUtilSeq.f90
OBJ_SEQ = $(addprefix $(DIR_SEQ)/,$(SRC_SEQ:.f90=.o))
SRC_PAR = explicitPar.f90 explUtilPar.f90 updateBound.f90 readParam.f90
OBJ_PAR = $(addprefix $(DIR_PAR)/,$(SRC_PAR:.f90=.o))

all: explicitSeq explicitPar

explicitSeq: $(OBJ_SEQ)
        $(GFORTRAN) -o $@ $^

$(DIR_SEQ)/%.o: $(DIR_SEQ)/%.f90
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $< -o $@

explicitPar: $(OBJ_PAR)
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -o $@ $^

$(DIR_PAR)/%.o: $(DIR_PAR)/%.f90
        $(MPI_FORTRAN) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_SEQ): | $(DIR_SEQ)
$(OBJ_PAR): | $(DIR_PAR)

$(DIR_SEQ):
        mkdir $@
        cp -pf $(SRC_SEQ) $@

$(DIR_PAR):
        mkdir $@
        cp -pf $(SRC_PAR) $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o explicitSeq explicitPar
        rm -f $(DIR_SEQ)/*
        rmdir $(DIR_SEQ)
        rm -f $(DIR_PAR)/*
        rmdir $(DIR_PAR)
```

Unfortunately, I have to type 3 times "make" consecutively to get the 2 executables. Here's the output of these 3 "makes" :

**First "make" :**

```
$ make
mkdir tmpSeqDir
cp -pf explicitSeq.f90 explUtilSeq.f90 tmpSeqDir
gfortran -Wall -o explicitSeq tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.o tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.o
gfortran: error: tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.o: No such file or directory
gfortran: error: tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'explicitSeq' failed
make: *** [explicitSeq] Error 1
```

**Second "make" :**

```
$ make
gfortran -Wall -c tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.f90 -o tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.o
gfortran -Wall -c tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.f90 -o tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.o
gfortran -Wall -o explicitSeq tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.o tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.o
mkdir tmpParDir
cp -pf explicitPar.f90 explUtilPar.f90 updateBound.f90 readParam.f90 tmpParDir
mpif90 -Wall -o explicitPar tmpParDir/explicitPar.o tmpParDir/explUtilPar.o tmpParDir/updateBound.o tmpParDir/readParam.o
gfortran: error: tmpParDir/explicitPar.o: No such file or directory
gfortran: error: tmpParDir/explUtilPar.o: No such file or directory
gfortran: error: tmpParDir/updateBound.o: No such file or directory
gfortran: error: tmpParDir/readParam.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'explicitPar' failed
make: *** [explicitPar] Error 1
```

**Third "make" :**

```
$ make
mpif90 -Wall -c tmpParDir/explicitPar.f90 -o tmpParDir/explicitPar.o
mpif90 -Wall -c tmpParDir/explUtilPar.f90 -o tmpParDir/explUtilPar.o
mpif90 -Wall -c tmpParDir/updateBound.f90 -o tmpParDir/updateBound.o
mpif90 -Wall -c tmpParDir/readParam.f90 -o tmpParDir/readParam.o
mpif90 -Wall -o explicitPar tmpParDir/explicitPar.o tmpParDir/explUtilPar.o tmpParDir/updateBound.o tmpParDir/readParam.o
```

Is it possible to do only a simple "make" to compile all instead of having to type 3 times "make" ?

I suspect the lines `cp -pf $(SRC_SEQ) $@` and `cp -pf $(SRC_PAR) $@` to cause problems relatively to `$(DIR_SEQ)/%.f90` and `$(DIR_PAR)/%.f90` dependences.

Comment: You need to write your variable names in `$()` when accessing (reading) them. The form without `$()` is only used in assignments.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Could you take a look please on my **UPDATE 1** and  **UPDATE 2** ?

Comment: The rule `explicitSeq: $(DIR_SEQ)/$(OBJ_SEQ)` will evaluate to `explicitSeq: tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.f90 explUtilSeq.f90` (notice the missing path for the second file) which is not what we want. Why its claiming not to know how to make this I don't know however. Will look into it later. BTW which make are you using?

Comment: @Vroomfondel How to produce for `explicitSeq` target, the list of paths `tmpSeqDir/explicitSeq.f90 tmpSeqDir/explUtilSeq.f90` ? i.e with the variables `$(DIR_SEQ)` and `$(OBJ_SEQ)`or wildcards ?

Comment: See my makefile: `$(addprefix ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the double compile comes from the rule:

```
$(OBJ_SEQ): $(SRC_SEQ)
        $(GFORTRAN) -c $<
```

`$<` names only *the first* prerequisite which in all cases is `explicitSeq.f90` - your other object files aren't updated at all because their recipes don't create the target!

For your second question: that's a tricky one. A *very tricky* one IMHO. Effectively you are asking for a multi-architecture build with the added complexity that you want *both* architectures build in one makefile. I am not proficient enough to lay out a multi-arch solution, much less in a stackoverflow answer, but for the moment I came up with a solution which violates [Paul's third rule](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule3) nevertheless its simple.
For further reading, I refer you to [Paul's Multiarchitecture Builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/#vpath) which has a ton of good info.

Now to the solution: you need a way to specify the files which shall be compiled by "the other" compiler. As the filename ending is obviously no option *and* I don't know if you ever have the necessity to compile the same file with one as well as the other compiler, I recommend different directories for the object files. As I don't have Fortran source nor compilers, I used C and C++ to take over the roles of sequential and parallel code. I think you can easily adapt it to your system:

```
.PHONY: all     
all: objectoriented procedural

PROC_DIR = proc
OBJ_DIR = oo

OBJ_SRC = cppbaz.c
PROC_SRC = bar.c
SHARED_SRC = foo.c

# deduce the object files from the sources
OBJECT = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(OBJ_SRC:.c=.o) $(SHARED_SRC:.c=.o))
PROCED = $(addprefix $(PROC_DIR)/,$(PROC_SRC:.c=.o) $(SHARED_SRC:.c=.o))

# pattern rules for the compilation - as we violate Paul's 3rd rule, we
# need to give these, otherwise make executes empty recipes:
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    g++ -c -o $@ $<

$(PROC_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

# targets for the binaries
objectoriented: $(OBJECT)
    @echo linking $^
    -gcc -o $@ $^

procedural: $(PROCED)
    @echo linking $^
    -gcc -o $@ $^

# create destination directories, if not present
$(OBJECT): | $(OBJ_DIR)
$(PROCED): | $(PROC_DIR)    
$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@
$(PROC_DIR):
    mkdir $@
```

One more thing: I used a VPATH to locate the source files:

`make VPATH=srcdir_a:srcdir_b:othersrcdir` which tells make where to find the source files which are needed for the compilation.

Comment: -@Vroomfondel thanks for your help. I don't understand the lines `$(OBJECT): | $(OBJ_DIR)`and `$(PROCED): | $(PROC_DIR) `: what do they do ? I understand the line `$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@`: it creates the directory with $(OBJ_DIR) name but I didn't see  in documentation the two lines in this comment above. Regards

Comment: `target: | order-only-prerequisite` this makes the target dependant on the _existence_ but not the _timestamp_ of the prerequisite. Order-only should be renamed to existence-only IMHO. For directories this is exactly what we want: if its there, fine no matter the last modification, if not, create it.

Comment: -@Vroomfondel I got it : as you can see in **UPDATE 3** and in your solution, my error is that I didn't realize that rule `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c` determines automatically the right sources `*.c` as a function of defined  `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` object files: I thought that `%.c`was corresponding to all the `*.c`sources (Seq and Par sources)  of my directory. Thanks a lot !